# Synchronization-possible start of the sequence

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, thread-safety, semaphore

I am very confused about the output of these processes. Can anyone help me to find the possible start of the sequence?

```
semaphore mutex = 1;
semaphore times_a = 2;
semaphore times_b = 0;

A:

 repeat forever:
  P(times_a)
  P(mutex)
    <A1>
  V(mutex)
  V(times_b)



B:

repeat forever:
 P(times_b)
 P(mutex)
   <B1>
 V(mutex)
 V(times_a)
```

The concurrent execution of A and B produces
an infinite sequence of  and . Which
one is the only possible start of the sequence:

1. A1, A1, B1, A1, A1, B1, A1, A1, B1, ...
2. A1, B1, A1, A1, B1, A1, B1, A1, A1, ...
3. A1, B1, A1, B1, A1, B1, A1, B1, A1, ...
4. A1, A1, B1, B1, A1, B1, B1, A1, A1, ...

Comment: Yeah I've got the point. Thanks a lot! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer should be

```
3. A1, B1, A1, B1, A1, B1, A1, B1, A1, ...
```

To understand the question better, I'll highlight these points.

- There are only 2 threads (A and B).
- Processes of both repeat forever.

When we just see the code, there are certain things we can understand about the characteristics of the output,

- The first letter should be A1. Indeed all the options state that. Now try dig a bit deeper to find disclaimers. If you carefully see, you can identify followings.
- At any point of the sequence, `(no of A1) > (no of B1)`. Because at least one **dedicated** 'A' cycle is required to run in order to enable a 'B' cycle to start.
- At any point of the sequence, `(no of A1) ≤ (no of B1 + 2)`. Because the maximum amount of 'A' cycles that can run without the support of a 'B' cycle is 2.

i.e `(no of B1) < (no of A1) ≤ (no of B1 + 2)`

From the first part, you can discard (4).
From the second part, you can discard (1) and (2).

I think you can understand my explanation. Please raise questions if any. :))